# How do I correctly use Recursion in MATLAB?

Tags: recursion, matlab

I have a simple m file that I have created as a recursive function:

```
function[velocity] = terminal(m,c,t,vi)
%inputs:
% m = mass
% c = coeffcient of drag
% t = time
% vi = initial velocity

if t==18, velocity = vi+(9.8-c/m*(vi))*2;
    return 
end

velocity = vi+(9.8-c/m*(vi))*2;
velocity  %used to print out velocity for debugging
terminal(m,c,t+2,velocity);
end
```

The calculation of velocity is being done correctly as it prints out every recursion.  However the "ans" that is returned at the end is the first calculated value of recursion.  My question is how do I correctly setup a matlab function recursively?  Or can it be done, and is it better to use a loop?

Comment: In Matlab, a loop would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear with me, haven't done a lot of Matlab for some time now.

But I would simply call your function iteratively:

```
velocity = vi
for t = 0:2:18
    velocity = velocity+(9.8-c/m*(velocity))*2;
end
```

Then for each instance of t it would calculate velocity for a given initial velocity and update that value with it's new velocity.

To have it take incremental steps with a size of 2, [simply add your step size to it.](http://cnx.org/content/m13258/1.3/)

Updated in response to the comments

Comment: "vi" can be replaced by "velocity" (using only this variable).
(and "for t = 0:2:18" if you want exactly the same comportment)

Comment: @KronoS : that the second part of my comment.

Comment: If the idea is for the final value of `velocity` to represent the summation of the incremental effects that gravitational acceleration and drag will have for each time step given an initial velocity `vi`, then you should change `vi` to `velocity` in the loop and add the initialization `velocity = vi;` before the loop is entered.

Answer (score 6):

Although my answer will stray away from programming and into the realm of calculus, it should be noted that you can solve your problem both without recursion *or* a loop since you can *exactly* solve for an equation `v(t)` using integration. It appears that you are modeling [Stokes' drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers_.E2.80.94_Stokes.27_drag) on a falling body, so you can use the [fourth formula from this integration table](http://integral-table.com/) to compute a final velocity `vFinal` that is achieved after falling for a time `tDelta` given a starting velocity `vInitial`. Here is the resulting formula you would get:

```
vFinal = 9.8*m/c + (vInitial - 9.8*m/c)*exp(-c*tDelta/m);
```

This will be a more accurate answer than approximating `vFinal` by making sequential steps forward in time (i.e. the [Euler method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), which can display significant errors or instabilities when the time steps that are taken are too large).

Comment: I'd go with his answer @Kronos, as it's better to have a correct answer than 'just' doing what the book said

Comment: while it's been a while from when I worked on this, I believe that the programming was the more important aspect of the issue at hand.  I wasn't able to find any questions on how to correctly perform recursion in matlab, and thought that I'd use this as an example.  However, you are correct in that this is more exact.

Answer (score 1):

```
velocity = terminal(m,c,t+2,velocity)
```

should work.

Comment: Please explain what and where you mean exactly?  Do I do this within the terminating if statement or at the end when I recursively call the function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with recursion here is it adds function call overhead for each time through. This will make your code far slower and less efficient in matlab. Use a loop instead and you will be far ahead of things. Yes, there are cases where recursion is a valuable tool. But in many cases a carefully written loop is the better solution.

Finally, when you DO use recursion, learn when to apply tools like memoization to improve the behavior of the algorithm. Memoization simply means to not recompute that which you have already done. For example it is possible to use recursion for a fibonacci sequence, but this is a terribly inefficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of your function is `velocity`. Matlab will return the last value assigned to velocity in the function body. Even though `velocity` is assigned deeper into the recursion, this doesn't matter to Matlab.
`velocity` in the next call to `terminal()` is a different variable!

Changing the final line to

```matlab
function[velocity] = terminal(m,c,t,vi)
%inputs:
% m = mass
% c = coeffcient of drag
% t = time
% vi = initial velocity

if t==18, velocity = vi+(9.8-c/m*(vi))*2;
    return 
end

velocity = vi+(9.8-c/m*(vi))*2;
velocity  %used to print out velocity for debugging
velocity = terminal(m,c,t+2,velocity);
end
```

Gives the expected result.